# How to get all build variants of my app available to a gradle task?

Tags: android, gradle, groovy

I have 3 different build variant in my java gradle project. `alpha`, `beta`, `gamma`. I have to print the names of all the build variants available from a gradle task. can someone please show a sample gradle task for the same?

TIA!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to list all flavors in buildConfig via gradle in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35478189/how-to-list-all-flavors-in-buildconfig-via-gradle-in-android)

Comment: Hey Jake, thanks for answering.. The answer above lists all the product flavors. I actually need the build variants. (product flavor + build type) combinations

Comment: You can try with "./gradlew sourceSets". But i think it shows you a bit more data than you would need

Comment: @SandeshBaliga Sorry I should have mentioned, some of the answers handle all the build variants, then filter (which you won't need to do) e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/60209108/608312

Answer (score 0):

./gradlew outgoingVariants

this works on gradle 7.5.1